# Change subtotal on cart with observer

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, subtotal

I tried to change the subtotal value of cart. I used `sales_quote_collect_totals_after` event to change it, and inside the observer, i do the code below, but nothing change, where should i change the subtotal value?

***Observer :***

```
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
$total=$quote->getBaseSubtotal();
$quote->setSubtotal(0);
$quote->setBaseSubtotal(0);

$quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
$quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);

$quote->setGrandTotal(0);
$quote->setBaseGrandTotal(0);
```

Comment: You have to override TotalsCollector i think so . Private property you are not able to set like this.

Comment: Im still new with magento, can you tell me how to do it?